# Moving article between sites in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wiki

We are avid useres of the wiki functionality in our sharepoint 2007 server.
Now we want to restructure the information hierarchy. This means its required to move articles between sites (meaning categories on the same Sharepoint instance) and if possible also reorder and rename some existing sites (again meaning categories).

I have already looked in built in functionality, the Sharepoint API/Webservices and the DB but none presented itself as a viable way to move the content.

Whats the best way to do this migration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Site Content and Structure in Site Administration to move wiki pages.[Work with site content and structure](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx)

You can also have a look at www.sharepointproducts.com where you can download a free version of a tool (CopyMove for SharePoint) that can also move Wiki pages across site collections. It does, however, not update the links on the Wiki pages

Comment: The Options described on your linked MSISDN site are not available to me. Ill check with our IT-Department if there are any additional rights which my account might not have at this time.

Comment: You probably need Site Admin rights.

Comment: Our administration team just told be that the described feature is only available for none sharepoint sites. My Account has site Administrator rights, the menu option is not available.